# Group by Multiple columns and case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to present the orderdata group by Month and card type for an year like this:

```
MONTH   CARDTYPE ORDER_CNT
201201  AMEX    10,835
201201  DISC    6,542
201201  MC  2,675
201202  AMEX    66,817
201202  DISC    36,581
201202  MC  165,683
```

The table from which I can get the data has orders by each day of the month. I used the following SQL to group the order count for  each day of the month by card type:

(

```
SELECT cardtype,orderdate,COUNT (distinct(orderserialno)) FROM tablename
where orderdate between '01-jan-2012' and '31-dec-2012'
GROUP BY cardtype,orderdate
```

)

Now I need to present this data in the above form by using case statement as I will have to group it by month, however I am not able to do that. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using (MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle, etc)

Answer (score 1):

to group by month you can just use:

SQLServer:

```
group by year(dateField)+month(dateField)
```

or 
Oracle:

```
group by to_char(dateField, 'Year') + to_char(dateField, 'Month')
```

so for your query:

```
SELECT cardtype,COUNT (distinct(orderserialno)),year(dateField)+month(dateField)  as order_date  FROM tablename
where orderdate between '01-jan-2012' and '31-dec-2012'
GROUP BY cardtype,year(dateField)+month(dateField)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT to_number(substr('201201', 1, 4)) curr_year
      , to_number(substr('201201', -2, 2)) curr_month
      , 'AMEX' card_type FROM dual
  UNION ALL
 SELECT to_number(substr('201202', 1, 4))
      , to_number(substr('201202', -2, 2))
     , 'DISC' FROM dual
) 
ORDER BY curr_year, curr_month, card_type
/

CURR_YEAR    CURR_MONTH    CARD_TYPE
------------------------------------
2012         1             AMEX
2012         2             DISC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `GROUP BY` section like this :

```
GROUP BY cardtype, trunc(orderdate, 'MM')
```

and in the `SELECT` section you should use `to_char(orderdate, 'YYYYMM')` instead of orderdate