# SQL: GROUP BY multiple columns with CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL.

I'd like to use `GROUP BY` with a `CASE` statement, to group results in a particular way if `@myboolean` is true.

I've seen many examples of how to use `GROUP BY` and `CASE BY` with a single field, or how to use `GROUP BY` with multiple fields without a `CASE` statement.

I don't know how to combine the two. When I enclose the `GROUP BY` fields within the `CASE` statement, I get a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

So, this works:

```
GROUP BY 
/* This works with no enclosing CASE statement */
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
```

This produces a syntax error:

```
GROUP BY 
CASE WHEN (@myboolean=1)
  THEN
    field1,   <-- ERROR HERE:  Incorrect syntax near ','
    field2,
    field3,
    field4
  ELSE 
    field1
  END
```

I have already looked at these questions:

- [SQL: Group By with Case Statement for multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616346/sql-group-by-with-case-statement-for-multiple-fields): seems to be a `GROUP BY` either/or based on `CASE`, rather than group by multiple. No commas involved anyway.
- [Group by Multiple columns and case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549673/group-by-multiple-columns-and-case-statement): maybe I'm thick, but I can't see how this includes a case statement in the `GROUP BY` clause
- various others, less relevant

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Please note that I'm inheriting a very complex/long SQL statement, which I want to avoid altering too much. I don't want to split the query into two separate `SELECT` statements.

Comment: A CASE can only return one column/value, not several.

Comment: @jarlh thanks. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: the CASE does not work as you expect

Comment: `group by` directly associates with `aggregate` we have to also manage `select` statement

Comment: your ease expression doesnt make sense, you are saying when `@myboolean=1` then return `field1,field2,field3,field4`  , `THEN` clause should have one and only one value or expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use...

```
GROUP BY field1,
    CASE WHEN @myboolean=1 THEN field2 END,
    CASE WHEN @myboolean=1 THEN field3 END,
    CASE WHEN @myboolean=1 THEN field4 END
```

If `@myboolean` is not `1` that evaluates to `NULL` which doesn't affect the result.

If it's in a stored-procedure you can also use an `IF`.

Comment: If @myboolean will be 1 then should it true this all case condition?

Comment: @RahulDubey: if `@myboolean` is `1` the `CASE` evaluates to `true` and  the `THEN` clause returns the expression defined behind, so `field2`, `field3` or `field4`.

Comment: really nice answered by you.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
IF (@myboolean=1)
BEGIN
SELECT
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4

END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT
field1
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
field1
END
```